# How to create a suitable object for IndexedDB from a dynamically created input form

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I wish to save the values from the input boxes in a dynamically created form but I´m having some trouble constructing the object that is to put into the IndexedDB objestStore.
I need something like this:

`[{"name": "box1 value", "last name": "box2 value", "age": "box3 value"},{"name": "box4 value", "last name": "box5 value", "age": "box6 value"}]`

propriety names have to stay the same (equal to the indexes in the objectStore), only the values change.

The code:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var boxes = rows.getElementsByClassName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

       objectStore.put('values');

    };  
};
```

I'm trying JSON.stringify(); but I'm not getting it to work...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is: 
 - Give all input fields for the same property the same name attribute
 - retrieve for each row the values of these input fields
 - Construct the object
 - save the object.

In pseudo code:

```
for each (row in rows){
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = row.getElementByName('name').value;
  obj.lastname = row.getElementByName('lastname').value;
  obj.age = row.getElementByName('age').value;

  objectStore.put(obj)
}
```

Comment: Does this construct the pairs ("name": "box1 value"), does it carry the property name and the respective value?

Comment: What it does is creating a JSON object with 3 properties: name, lastname and age. These are also the names of the properties. In the value of these properties we store the value of the input field with the name of the property in the current row. I hope this anwsers your comment.